# how do i avoid instantiating variables within a function too often?

Tags: javascript

Lets say we have a function with lots of variables:

```
function foo () {
   let a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m;
   //Do some math
}

//Then we call this function over and over again

for (let i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
    foo();
}
```

I realise that if i declare the variables outside of foo(), the entire loop will go faster, because the variables inside of foo() are instantiated once, instead of 9999 times.

I would like to know if i can create a class similar to java, and store those variables like attributes, so they would only be instantiated once, and foo() can work with them, when i call the function.

Comment: How did you realise that declaring unused variables makes any difference? Have you investigated declaring the variables on the same scope where you declare the function (so that they are still visible to the function): `let a,b,c,d,e; function foo(){}`?

Comment: thats what i mean, but wouldnt doing that give other function access to those variables aswell?, lets say i use x and y alot with many functions

Comment: I would not worry about performance here at all. Put the variables where they need to be, as local as possible. You can worry about duplicated calculations or such, but the variables themselves do not contribute to slowness.

Comment: if you do have a performance issue, show the real code. This cannot be discussed in the abstract.

Comment: In general, I would do performance tests with tools like this:
https://jsbench.me/

Comment: "*create a class similar to java, and store those variables like attributes*" - use an object literal. No need for a class.